# How can I create a custom cleanup mode for git?

Tags: git, trac, git-commit

I'd like to have a commit message cleanup that will not necessarily remove lines beginning with a `#` in the message itself. The default `--cleanup=strip` removes **all** lines starting with a `#` character.

The reason being is unfortunately, the [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) engine's wiki formatter uses hashes in the beginning of a code block to denote the syntax type. This creates difficulty when using the engine's syntax in my commit messages.

Example:

```
Created demo of perl added to helloworld.pl

{{{
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
# say hi to the user.
print "hello world\n";

}}}

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD^1 <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   added:   helloworld.pl
# and so on and so forth...
```

I would like the following result in the final logged commit message:

```
commit 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Author: Danny <...>
Date:   Wed Apr 7 13:34:29 2010 -0400

     Created demo of perl added to helloworld.pl

     {{{
     #!/usr/bin/perl
     use strict;
     # say hi to the user.
     print "hello world\n";

     }}}
```

I'd like to use a custom filter that removes all lines beginning with a hash from the bottom of the commit message upwards. Leaving the lines in the message I have added alone. Where or how can I specify this in git?

Note, creating a sed or perl script to perform the operation is not a problem, just knowing *where to hook it* into git is the question.

My apologies on the confusion of my question, I hadn't realized how vague it was.

Comment: @Danny: I'm pretty sure you're asking this question about commit message cleanup (evidenced by the git-commit tag and "...embedded in the commit message...") - but your example doesn't look much like a commit message and you said "bottom of the file", not "bottom of the message". Assuming I've interpreted right, you might want to extend the example to a full commit message and clarify your phrasing a little bit.

Comment: The question is in reference to the commit message, I have attempted to clarify it accordingly.

Comment: for future reference, see also [Start a git commit message with a hashmark (#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll want to use two things to accomplish this:

- Specify the cleanup mode. `git commit` takes a `--cleanup=<mode>` option; you can use `--cleanup=whitespace` to prevent git from stripping any comments. The other choice you might want is verbatim, which (surprise) doesn't touch the message. See the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) for the other choices, if you're interested.
- Use the `commit-msg` hook to edit the message in place. In case you haven't used hooks before, the man page is called [githooks](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/githooks.html), and they're scripts placed in `.git/hooks` which are executed at the appropriate times. The `commit-msg` hook is executed with a single argument, the file containing the proposed commit message. It can edit the message in place, and if it returns failure (non-zero) the commit will be aborted. So, write your custom stripping script as `.git/hooks/commit-msg`, make sure it's executable, and you'll be set. Note that the hooks directory isn't tracked; if you want to share this with others, a common method is to place it somewhere inside your repository, then symlink `.git/hooks/commit-msg` to it.

Comment: The hooks aren't part of the config. If you'd like to place them in new repositories you create, you can use the `--template` option to `git init` and `git clone`. That lets you specify a template directory instead of the system-wide default one; the default hooks are all copied from the template directory's hooks directory. (See the git init man page http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html ) You could also edit the system-wide template (generally in `/usr/share/git-core/templates`) if you really wanted.

Comment: To make it easier to remember to use the template, you could place aliases in your .gitconfig - something like `myinit = init --template=<template directory>`.

Comment: Aside from using an alias, is there a way to set a default cleanup mode? I've looked around in the documentation to no avail. I'm either blind or it is simply not available