# Start a Git commit message with a hashmark (#)

Tags: git, commit, ticket-system, ticket-tracking

Git treats lines starting with `#` (hash, number sign, octothorpe, pound sign) as comment lines when committing. This is very annoying when working with a ticket tracking system, and trying to write the ticket number at the beginning of the line, e.g.

```
#123 salt hashed passwords
```

Git will simply remove the line from the commit message. Is there a way to escape the hash? I tried `\` and `!`, but nothing works. White space before `#` is preserved, so that's not a working solution to the problem either.

Comment: Why not adopt a convention like Bug#123?

Comment: @AlexBudovski because there's value in brevity.

Comment: Since git 1.8.2 (February 2013), `git config core.commentchar` allows to configure that comment character. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14931661/6309)

Comment: Since Git v2.0.0 (2014.05.21) `git commit --cleanup=scissors` will be more flexible. See detail in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37058066/603949)

Comment: I must say, I'm surprised the GitHub people didn't think about this problem when they decided to mark issue numbers with hashes!

Comment: `git config core.commentChar "@"` solved it for me. I rarely want to add E-Mails to git commits

Comment: @Michael To be fair, this convention was already used by Mantis, Trac, Redmine and probably others. I suppose that GitHub just decided to follow it instead of reinventing the wheel. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495/bug-tracker-setup-with-git-integration

Comment: Came here because I'm writing a commit message about a #define in C, and #define happens to be at the start of the line. I could futz about with the exact wording to make it not at the start of the line, or put in a space before the #, or some other workaround. Looks like I'll be using `--cleanup-=scissors` from now on.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with GitHub and everything to do with Git, which lies at the core of GitHub. And also, what @kelvin said.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

This behaviour is part of `git commit`'s default 'clean-up' behaviour. If you want to keep lines starting with `#` you can use an alternative clean-up mode.

E.g.

```
git commit --cleanup=whitespace
```

If you do this you have to be careful to remove all `#` lines that you don't want to appear in the commit.

Comment: The next question is: Where can I edit the commit message comments that git introduces which start by default with a # ?

Comment: @Alex: It's controlled by the `commit.template` git configuration variable.

Comment: This works great for amending existing commits also.  Eg: `git commit --amend --cleanup=whitespace`

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I was expecting to get rid of the predefined text with  git commit -t /dev/null but it is still showing that

Comment: As you are able to have a commit message of "#123 Commit message" as well as comments in clients such as GitHub for Mac and SourceTree I guess is what these clients are doing yes?

Comment: Then be careful during `git rebase --interactive` and using any commit message editing stanza (like reword or squash)

Comment: @JamesAndres, at least in git 1.7.1 (default on RHEL 6), `git commit --amend --cleanup=whitespace` does not preserve or restore any comment lines previously stripped out by git's cleanup mechanism.  Not sure what output you are looking at (I thought maybe it worked the way conflicts during cherry pick preserve the commit message for afterwards) but you will still have to get your `#desired lines` back through some other means or recreate them.

Comment: `--cleanup=verbatim` is also useful

Comment: Since this is 2020, everyone just wants [`--cleanup=scissors` and `[commit] cleanup = scissors`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058066/2809027) instead. Those do everything `--cleanup=whitespace` does as well as automatically stripping the commented changeset suffixing every commit message.

Answer (score 171):

Note that, since [git1.8.2 (February 2013)](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1443021), you can use a different character than '`#`' for the commented line in the commit message.

That allows you to use '`#`' for your bug number reference.

> Various "hint" lines Git gives when it asks the user to edit messages in the editor are commented out with '`#`' by default.
>
> The **`core.commentChar`** configuration variable can be used to customize this '`#`' to a different character.

---

In theory, you *could* put a `core.commentChar` word (multiple characters), but git 2.0.x/2.1 will be stricter (Q3 2014).

See [commit 50b54fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84c9dc2c5a2d34351a06554af32501d4f99990e9) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84c9dc2c5a2d34351a06554af32501d4f99990e9):

#### config: be strict on core.commentChar

> We don't support comment *strings* (at least not yet). And multi-byte character encoding could also be misinterpreted.
>
> The test with two commas is updated because it violates this. It's added with the patch that [introduces `core.commentChar` in eff80a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84c9dc2c5a2d34351a06554af32501d4f99990e9) (Allow custom "comment char" - 2013-01-16). It's not clear to me *why* that behavior is wanted.

---

git 2.0.x/2.1 (Q3 2014) will add an automatic selection for `core.commentChar`:
See [commit 84c9dc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84c9dc2c5a2d34351a06554af32501d4f99990e9)

> When `core.commentChar` is "`auto`", the comment char starts with '`#`' as in default but if it's already in the prepared message, find another char in a small subset. This should stop surprises because git strips some lines unexpectedly.
>
> Note that git is not smart enough to recognize '`#`' as the comment char in custom templates and convert it if the final comment char is different.
> It thinks '#' lines in custom templates as part of the commit message. So don't use this with custom templates.

The list of candidate characters for "auto" are:

```
# ; @ ! $ % ^ & | :
```

That means a command like `git commit -m '#1 fixed issue'` will automatically switch the commentChar to '`;`', because '`#`' was used in the commit message.

---

See "[**Making a hash of things – using `#s` in Git commit messages**](https://blog.tdwright.co.uk/2018/09/15/making-a-hash-of-things-using-s-in-git-commit-messages/)" by [**Tom Wright**](https://blog.tdwright.co.uk/about-tom/)

> The Stackoverflow answer I linked to above also mentions a feature in Git that will choose a comment character automatically, based on the characters you use in commit messages.
>
> ```
> git config --global core.commentChar auto
> ```
>
> Sounds great right?
> Unfortunately, it only changes the comment character based on commits made *after* you turn it on; it doesn’t use your commit history to inform the choice.
>
> To my mind, this is a great feature hobbled by poor execution.
> It seems like a feature that would be effective only if it were on by default:
>
> - One group of people will simply avoid using hashes in commits because they are familiar with the consequences.
> - Others (like us) will only realise they need to change the comment character when they need to do a rebase. It doesn’t make sense in this situation to add a new commit just to trigger the desired behaviour.
> - A third group of people will consciously accept early on that they need to change the default comment character and will simply choose an alternative.
>
> In other words, having this feature available as a non-default option helps virtually no-one.
> Since having it on by default would do nothing to harm any users, and would remove a pain point for some users, I can’t work out why this isn’t the case.
> Git isn’t famed for its usability, but to have a fix available and not to turn it on seems gratuitously user-hostile.

---

Note: Git 2.41 (Q2 2023) adds:

See [commit d3b3419](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3b3419f8f287cd9d17be30e50937cbc7c4951ff) (27 Mar 2023) by [Kristoffer Haugsbakk (`LemmingAvalanche`)](https://github.com/LemmingAvalanche).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5c93cfd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c93cfdafd64222043837caae87ea9c9e6c89da1), 31 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3b3419f8f287cd9d17be30e50937cbc7c4951ff): tell the user that we expect an ASCII character
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kristoffer Haugsbakk</sup>

> Commit [50b54fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50b54fd72a8776d628365c7760bc922902d29d11) ("`config`: be strict on `core.commentChar`", 2014-05-17, Git v2.1.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e2600dd6a2acf8d2e9c0923184ca2335b861138) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0953113bb5687f42bcdfc3d20dd3a125784ad383)) notes that “multi-byte character encoding could also be misinterpreted”, and indeed a multi-byte codepoint (non-ASCII) is not accepted as a valid `core.commentChar`.

The message is now:

```
core.commentChar should only be one ASCII character
                                    ^^^^^
```

---

This is confirmed with Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f9b731bdeccffa1b13e5edf4bc0428b8d49704e): The "`core.commentChar`" configuration variable only allows an ASCII character, which was not clearly documented before.

See [commit fb7c556](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb7c556f580f725dc9786daf5c1fef8a279d8615) (05 Mar 2024) by [Kristoffer Haugsbakk (`LemmingAvalanche`)](https://github.com/LemmingAvalanche).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 26ab20c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26ab20ccb26d5ead9f915e50b5511456a955f074), 14 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb7c556f580f725dc9786daf5c1fef8a279d8615): document `core.commentChar` as ASCII-only
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Manlio Perillo</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kristoffer Haugsbakk</sup>

> [d3b3419](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3b3419f8f287cd9d17be30e50937cbc7c4951ff) ("`config`: tell the user that we expect an ASCII character", 2023-03-27, Git v2.41.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c93cfdafd64222043837caae87ea9c9e6c89da1) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/140b9478dad5d19543c1cb4fd293ccec228f1240)) updated an error message to make clear that this option specifically wants an ASCII character but neglected to consider the config documentation.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fb7c556f580f725dc9786daf5c1fef8a279d8615/Documentation/config/core.txt#L524):

> messages consider a line that begins with this ASCII character

Comment: To fix syntax HL after this, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164624/edit-vim-syntax-highlighting-for-git-commit-messages

Comment: @Guten True, I have reworded the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported during interactive rebase.

Comment: @newbyca with what version of git do you see that not supported during an interactive rebase?

Comment: @VonC thanks for keeping me honest :) ...I was using msysgit 1.8.1. Just upgraded to 1.9.4 and rebase -i honors core.commentchar now. Thanks again!

Comment: So, to set this you can do, e.g: `$ git config --global core.commentchar ';'`

Comment: I love this answer. Oneliner for the new suggested solution: `git config --global core.commentChar auto`

Comment: Why on earth isn't "auto" the default? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: A nice [blog post from Tom, 2018](https://blog.tdwright.co.uk/2018/09/15/making-a-hash-of-things-using-s-in-git-commit-messages/) which redirects back to this SO answer :-) I found the post 1st, then the SO entry here. In the post there are a bit more details about `auto`

Comment: @KargWare Thank you for your feedback. I have included a reference to that post in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 130):

Answers here are good and detailed, but for a git noob like me customizing git config options isn't so obvious. Here is an example to change from `#` to `;` for comment characters:

```bash
git config core.commentChar ";"
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: This *also* changes the default commented text that git adds to a commit message when one uses `git commit` to open up the configured editor to edit a commit message !

Comment: For one-off fixes, use this: `git -c core.commentChar="|" commit --amend` (replace `|` with whatever you want).

Answer (score 64):

You can use the command line option `-m`:

```bash
git commit -m "#123 fixed"
```

Comment: But this is a horrible commit message. make sure to include what the bug was and how it was fixed

Comment: the commit messages is ok as long as there is a number of the bug

Comment: Not if the bug tracking system suddenly gets corrupted and you don't have a backup! :)

Comment: Also not good if your company migrates from jira to any other tracker

Comment: You could do something like: ```git commit -m "#123 fixed" -m "Long commit"``` it also works with --amend

Comment: this causes problems when you want to commit --amend to fix an incorrect issue number. The amend is not accepted because it looks like a commented line.

Answer (score 63):

If you're doing an interactive rebase, then when you save your commit message with nothing in it (because the `#` at the beginning has made it a comment and therefore it's been ignored) git will show you what to do:

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
Could not amend commit after successfully picking 5e9159d9ce3a5c3c87a4fb7932fda4e53c7891db... 123 salt hashed passwords
This is most likely due to an empty commit message, or the pre-commit hook
failed. If the pre-commit hook failed, you may need to resolve the issue before
you are able to reword the commit.
You can amend the commit now, with

        git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

        git rebase --continue
```

So, just amend the message:

```bash
git commit --amend -m "#123 salt hashed passwords"
```

and continue the rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: This is correct for someone who pushed the commit already, but want to change the message

Comment: It also applies to new commits if you enter a message using your editor and it has a hash at the beginning.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. # at the beginning of comment is still more readable than at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 48):

`git commit --cleanup=scissors` should be used. It's added to [Git v2.0.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt) on 2014.05.21

from `git commit --help`

```
--cleanup=<mode>
  scissors
    Same as whitespace, except that everything from (and including) the line
    "# ------------------------ >8 ------------------------" is truncated if the message
    is to be edited. "#" can be customized with core.commentChar.
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is any better than using `commit.cleanup = whitespace` and removing `# …` commentary by-hand, as @CharlesBailey has already suggested.  `scissors`-mode just additionally cleans up the scissors-syntax used by `git` `format-patch`/`mailinfo`/`am`; _it does **not** use the `…-- >8 --…` syntax when adding commentary to commit messages_.

Comment: 1. I think it's better because I don't need to "removing `# ...` commentary by-hard.   2. I'm not so sure about the second part of your comment, the `scissors` mode is definitely in the `git commit --help`. What version of `git` are you using? @SlippD.Thompson

Comment: Huh? `whitespace` mode offers stripping of 1. leading and trailing empty lines, 2. trailing whitespace, 3. collapse consecutive empty lines. `scissors` offers stripping of 1. leading and trailing empty lines, 2. trailing whitespace, 3. collapse consecutive empty lines, 4. everything from (and including) the line `# -…- >8 -…-`. However, scissors lines (`# -…- >8 -…-`) are only inserted when using `git-format-patch`/`mailinfo`/`am`. Therefore for a normal `git-commit`/`merge`/`rebase`/`cherry-pick` workflow, `scissors` stripping mode offers zero benefits over `whitespace` mode.  v2.11.0

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson What version of git are you using? I'm using 2.8.3 and `git commit --cleanup=scissors` *DOES* prepend the `# ------------------------ >8 ------------------------` line before the `git status` info. Like below: `
# ------------------------ >8 ------------------------
# Do not touch the line above.
# Everything below will be removed.
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   .gitignore
`

Comment: _“What version of git are you using?”_ I already answered that question for you.  |   _“git commit --cleanup=scissors DOES prepend the # ------------------------ >8 ------------------------ line”_ It doesn't for me: http://imgur.com/a/GiB2j  |  Either older versions of git had this behavior and it's now been removed, or you have another config setting besides `commit.cleanup = scissors` that's doing this for you. _P.S. I tried with both `commit.cleanup` in `.gitconfig` and `git commit --cleanup=scissors`; no dice._

Comment: I believe I've gotten to the bottom of this.  Git does indeed insert the `# ------------------------ >8 ------------------------` before the status txt “It looks like you may be …”_ when using `scissors`; however, it inserts the scissors line _after_ the `# Conflicts: …` text.  I had `commit.status = false` set in my `.gitconfig`, so I wasn't seeing any status text, only the conflicts text.  I stand corrected; changing to upvote.

Comment: Permanently enable this by adding `[commit] cleanup = scissors` to `~/.gitconfig` and your keyboard-weary fingers will thank you by not screeching in pain.

Answer (score 10):

It just suffices to start the commit message with a space char   just before the `#` char.

Then `git` stops regarding the line as a comment and `github` can use the hashed ticket number without any problems.

`vim`'s default syntax highlighting even suggests the feature by changing the color from *commentish* to *contentish*.

[image]

Comment: But will the leading space be included in the commit message or will it be stripped? I'd rather not have commit messages start with an invisible character. That will lead to problems down the road

Comment: @knittl: The leading space will not get stripped. That's the whole purpose - otherwise the line would be treated as a comment. Can you elaborate on what problems this practice can lead to? I haven't encountered any so far.

Comment: Several problems and issues I can think of: 1) It is inconsistently indented 2) (Too) Simple scripts to extract the ticket number might fail on the leading whitespace 3) Why store one extra space character with every single commit message? 4) Too easy to forget [5) and finally: it does not actually start the commit message with the hash character, but a space ;)]

Comment: @knittl: Well yeah, you cannot both have the cake and eat it. I mentioned this approach because it is IMO by far the simplest while allowing both to start the message with a hash (not counting whitespaces) and to preserve the feature of hash-based commenting.

Only the 2nd point is a sort of problem, but more of a hypothetical one IMHO.

Thanks for the discourse anyway;-)

Comment: “Well yeah, you cannot both have the cake and eat it.”—You can. See the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different prefix for the ticket number. Or prepend a word to the ticket number, like "Bug #42". Or prepend a single space character to the line; if you wish to remove that whitespace you can add a commit-hook for that.

I personally would rather not have this sort of commit message manipulation done by a hook because it can be very irritating when it triggers when you don't want it to. The easiest solution is probably to re-think the problem.

Comment: different wording is only a workaround for the problem. if project guidelines state that a commit message must begin with the ticket id, then it will not work. and a post-commit hook is very ugly. i think i should report this "bug" to the git developers

Comment: Don't bother, that'd be wrong. Don't ask the git developers to work according to your guidelines. You wouldn't ask Dennis Ritchie to change the C language so it supports you variable names convention of starting with a hash character, right? The same applies here. If commit messages allow comments then this adds support for interesting things, like opening the commit editor with the diff added and commented out so you don't need to remember your exact changes. What's wrong with preserving the leading space character?

Comment: supporting escape characters in git's commit message wouldn't be such a big deal

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable feature request. Especially in light of the fact that Trac, AFAICT, doesn't associate a commit to a bug slip if the commit message doesn't start with the slip number, starting with a hash. So it's not just someone's standards, it's a tool's required syntax. Let the Git devs decide whether it's worthwhile or not. (And yes, Trac could *also* fix the problem. There's nothing wrong with requesting that Git do what it can, too.)

Comment: “Especially in light of the fact that Trac, AFAICT, doesn't associate a commit to a bug slip if the commit message doesn't start with the slip number, starting with a hash.” — in my limited experience with Trac, something like `#xxx` occurring anywhere in the commit message will link to the issue. It doesn’t have to be at the start of the commit. Maybe this is something that has changed in the last five years?

Comment: We use ### markdown in our github pull request templates, and since github will take a single-commit PR's commit message as the PR description, its handy to have the same commit template as the PR template. Then you can handle the commit message and the PR description in one shot. But this git behavior nukes the ### heading markdown

Answer (score 1):

All my commits starts with `#issueNumber` so I put this boilerplate to my `vim .git/hooks/commit-msg`:

```bash
NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //') 
echo "$NAME"' '$(cat "$1") > "$1"
```

So let's suppose we have branch `#15` and we make commit message `add new awesome feature`. With this approach final commit message will be `#15 add new awesome feature`.

Answer (score 0):

[`!` is a history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) that's why it didn't worked.

> History expansions are introduced by the appearance of the history expansion character, which is `!` by default.

You can use `$` with single `'` quotes ([Escape a Single Quote in Single Quote String in Bash](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/single-quote-within-single-quoted-string)):

```bash
$ git commit -m $'#228 update to a new version! margin of error is 33% | 33^*0.22;'
# commit message: #228 update to a new version! margin of error is 33% | 33^*0.22;
```

```bash
$ git commit -m $'docs!: new API reference for GPS horse navigation'
# commit message: docs!: new API reference for GPS horse navigation
```

If used without `$` and `'` but with `"`:

```bash
$ git commit -m "docs!: new API reference for GPS horse navigation"
bash:  : unrecognized history modifier
```

If used with `"` and escape `\` (`\` will still be there or I was doing something wrong):

```bash
$ git commit -m "docs\!: new API reference for GPS horse navigation"
# commit message: docs\!: new API reference for GPS horse navigation
```

Comment: How does this answer the question of having a `#` as first character in a commit message? This answer doesn't even contain a `#` (except for comments)

Comment: @knittl answer (using `$` with `'`) meant to escape any characters, including `#`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: But it's not required, simply use single quotes and `git commit -m '…'`. This has been part of all answers here for the last 12 years. I don't see which new information this answer adds, except explaining shell quoting rules which are not what the question is about. The `$` is not required in any of your commands (and only works in bash)