# Start a git commit message with a hashmark (#) with vim

Tags: git, vim, git-bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start a git commit message with a hashmark (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark)

I have something to do with my latest commit as I have to give a **hashmark** as the starting line for all my commit message

for example : 
- **#fix** email : send something useful
- **#dev** html-email : create cross platform layout

but accidentally I forgot the hashmark, I wrote
- **fix** html-email : fix layout for outlook
(notice the missing hashmark)

and I did 
- git reset --soft HEAD^ 
- git commit -c ORIG_HEAD

but everytime I put hashmark on the firstline, the vim will ignore it.
- I've tried using '\' , but the backslash character was printed in the commit message.
- I also tried using 'space' , and the whitespace appear before the first character of my commit message.

**Q : how do I put hashmark (#) as the starting line in my commit message using vim, so it wont be ignored ?**

note :
I'm using git-bash for windows.

Comment: This question has been answered in this other question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark

Comment: BTW, Using `git commit --amend` is identical to your two commands `git reset --soft HEAD^; git commit -c HEAD@{1}` (not `ORIG_HEAD`, that's something else), except it's simpler.

Comment: It's possible to work around this but... why? *Requiring* the one comment character in commit messages is asking for all kinds of pain.

Comment: @phiggy yes of course I checked out that question, I'm asking whether I can solve this thing out directly with VIM ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$ git commit --cleanup verbatim
```

to prevent any cleanup of the file.  (No lines will be removed.)