# vim syntax highlighting for git commit messages - custom commentchar

Tags: git, vim, comments, syntax-highlighting

As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14931661/835945), since Git 1.8.2 you can use `core.commentchar` config value to change commit message comments to something else than the default `#` (hashmark or hashsign).

That is a life-saver e.g. if your commit message policy wants you to start commit message with ticket number:

```
#123 Fixed array indices
```

Sad part is that this breaks Vim syntax highlighting.

How can you bring the beauty back?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should try to run `:verbose syntax`.  The active syntax file is probably `$VIMRUNTIME\syntax\gitcommit.vim` ([github version](https://github.com/tpope/vim-git/blob/master/syntax/gitcommit.vim) which is likely in your `.vim`).

It will tell you which syntax line will trigger the formatting as comment.

You'll probably see something like :

```
 gitcommitComment xxx match /^#.*/
     links to Comment
```

or

```
 syn match   gitcommitComment   "^#.*"
```

meaning it matches every line starting by `#`.

You might be able to modify it so that a `#` on the first line is not considered as a comment. I don't know `syntax` format enough to give you a full solution.

```
 \%^   match the beginning of file
 \%1l  match line 1
 \%>1l match below line 1
```

So you might try to modify the gitComment pattern so that it does not work on line 1 of your git commit.

(I tried some things but did not manage to only exclude first line of comment ! It seems there is also a `diffComment` messing things up because gitcommit includes diff format with `syn include @gitcommitDiff syntax/diff.vim`)
)

For more details, see `:help syntax` and `:help pattern`.

Another good resource on syntax highligthing : [Learn Vim the Hard Way, chapter 46](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/46.html).

Comment: Worked!  I just add that to retain full HL functionality (like showing error on any text on 2nd line or coloring state details later in comments) I actually changed `#` to my `core.commentchar` (`'`) pretty *everywhere* in the file.  Time will show if it broke something though... ;)

Comment: Somebody knows if I can do this "adjustment" setting up my system by just running a system command eg. using ansible?