# Escape comment character (#) in git commit message

Tags: git, escaping

I have set mcedit as my editor for git commit messages. By default it ignores any lines starting with the `#` character. However odd this may seem, I need to be able to have the my commit message looking like this:

```
#FOO-123: Implement bar foo

Committing work in progress
```

The `#FOO-123: ...` is actually the key + title of an issue in our tracker. The tracker can automatically pick up these commit messages and add them to the issue.

Unfortunately, the first line gets treated like a comment and gets ignored.

I don't want to have to be committing from the command line by adding `-m` as it's inconvenient/ugly when you have multiple lines.

How could I work around this?

Comment: `git config core.commentChar "@"` solved it for me.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can try and define a different character for comments in commit message:

```
git config core.commentchar <another char>
```

As I mention in "[Start a git commit message with a hashmark (`#`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14931661/6309)", this setting is available since git 1.8.2 (February 2013).

In your case:

```
git config core.commentchar "*"
```

Note that you *could* in theory put a core.commentchar word (multiple characters), but git 2.0.x/2.1 will be stricter.

See [commit 50b54fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50b54fd72a8776d628365c7760bc922902d29d11) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds):

#### config: be strict on core.commentChar

> We don't support comment *strings* (at least not yet). And multi-byte character encoding could also be misinterpreted.
>
> The test with two commas is updated because it violates this. It's added with the patch that [introduces `core.commentChar` in eff80a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eff80a9fd990de3605063050dae32f969ef18ba8) (Allow custom "comment char" - 2013-01-16). It's not clear to me *why* that behavior is wanted.

---

[poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) also mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936252/escape-comment-character-in-git-commit-messsage/22936439?noredirect=1#comment35014981_22936439) to change the [commit template](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

> When editing the commit message, start the editor with the contents in the given file.
>   The **`commit.template`** configuration variable is often used to give this option implicitly to the command.

---

Note that Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) fixes a bug, as "`git interpret-trailers`" always treated '`#`' as the comment character, regardless of `core.commentChar` setting, which has been corrected.

See [commit 29c83fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29c83fc23f140c6d06e13916f40e6830616cfa29) (19 Jun 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3a50607](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a506079d2f3375dd1f4bbd0fe3793dd74fb7d2d), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### interpret-trailers: load default config
>
> The [`interpret-trailers` program](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29c83fc23f140c6d06e13916f40e6830616cfa29#diff-5fa73358d2a7f2344a7d52a8bd1dccdc) does not do the usual loading of config via `git_default_config()`, and thus does not respect many of the usual options.
>   In particular, we will not load `core.commentChar`, even though the underlying trailer code uses its value.
>
> This can be seen in the accompanying test, where setting `core.commentChar` to anything besides "`#`" results in a failure to treat the comments correctly.

Comment: So, if I'd like to use `*` for example, how would I do it?

Comment: @carlspring `git config core.commentchar *`

Comment: Note that you might want to change the default commit template too if you don’t always use `git commit -m`.

Comment: @poke good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: git config core.commentchar "*" worked for me you may need to restart your terminal application for effects to take place

Comment: What if I set my commentchar to * but my teammate has #? Wouldn't a commit amendment for a commit message "#532 Fixed translations" have no problems for me, but for my teammate it'd appear as commented out? Even if said teammate opened the commit message for rewriting, and immediately saved and closed. Wouldn't the commit message be empty then for him?

Comment: @ArturTagisow This is a local setting, so the commit message interpretation would indeed be different if that setting is not applied *consistently* across your team.