# how to and '#' in vim but not used with Comments

Tags: git, vim

i  want add a git commit by use vim, like the picture. 
second line, I want add a commit text "#2355 fix a bug of this issues", but the vim think this is a annotations , vim will ignore this line , so what should I do.

[image]

Comment: you can change the comment char `core.commentChar`, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936252/escape-comment-character-in-git-commit-message

Comment: thanks @Ôrel, i follow your tip ,resolved

Answer (score 3):

> Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.

Just don't start your commit message with `#`

```
fix bug #2355 of this issues
```

Comment: I have resolved with "git config core.commentchar '*' ". if start commit with # will  automatically associate the commit with the issuse.

Answer (score 2):

It's not vim, it's git: according to the documentation:

> A '#' or ';' character indicates a comment.

Note that you could change this per repository:

> ```
> core.CommentChar
>   Commands such as commit and tag that lets you edit messages consider
>   a line that begins with this character
>   commented, and removes them after the editor returns (default #).
> ```