# How to reference issue (gitlab, github) at the beginning of the message with "$ git commit"?

Tags: git, message, commit, commit-message

I am trying to reference some issue at my commit message, I want to put the issue identifier at the beginning of the message, but also using some text editor to edit commit message (the command is `git commit`).

When I try this `#10 my message here` that line is ignored, because at editor all lines starting with # are ignored.

I already see [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-the-issue-number-on-github-within-a-commit-message) but here all examples only refence the issue in the middle of the message, or if it's at the beginning of the message all examples uses:

`git commit -m "#10 my message"`

How can I use the text editor and start the commit message with my issue identifier? I thinking maybe there is something like // or ! to inform that this line should not be ignored.

Comment: Add some text before the `#`, such as "Resolves #10 blah blah"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the `git config core.commentchar "*"` [that I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22936439/6309): you can change what character ignores a line in a commit message.

You can even change it just for your commit command:

```
git -c core.commantchar="*" commit ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I mark as duplicad?

Comment: Sure, you can, but your title of your question might help other find this setting more easily