# Git commit message with letter #

Tags: git, commit-message, git-amend

I have a little problem.
In our company we have an agreement that all commits that related to some issue in bug tracker should start with `#<issue_number>` (for example, `#8956`). But git ignores all of the lines that starts with letter '#' when writing message using an editor. If I use `git commit -m '#<issue_number> <Message>'` there is no problem. But I want to amend commit and edit it's message without using `-m` flag. So is there a way to make git not to ignore lines starting with `#` when using editor to write commit message?

Comment: Actually you are right, this my question is a duplicate of other question, but I searched for it both with Google's and Stackoverflow's search engines and didn't find it (maybe because I didn't know the correct name for '#' letter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either commit by passing the commit message via command line:

```
git commit -m '#1 fixed issue'
```

If you want to enter the commit message using a text editor you need to keep one space at the beginning of the line before the `#`.

---

By default git is using the `#` as the so called *cleanup character*. You can change this behaviour by passing a different character:

```
git commit --cleanup='@'
```

Thanks [@CharlesBailey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788642/171318) for this information.

---

Btw, your company should rethink about the agreement as it breaks the default git workflow.

Comment: git commit --cleanup=whitespace This works for me.

Comment: That is not my choice to start commit with '#'.