# How to retrieve git's commentchar via script?

Tags: git, bash, command-line

I'm trying to fix a git hook which does modify the commit message. But it assumes one uses `#` as `core.commentchar`.

Now I would like to retrieve the `core.commentchar`. Is there an easy way or do I have to write some logic by my own?

I tried

```
$ git config --get core.commentchar
```

This works just fine for custom comment chars but fails to retrieve the default one. Is there any simple command to retrieve the correct comment character? Or am I supposed to check if the above command returns an empty value and know it means it is `#`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the `core.commentchar` isn't explicitly defined, then the default one is '`#`'
(see [`environment.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/84c9dc2c5a2d34351a06554af32501d4f99990e9/environment.c#L71))

As I mention in "[Start a git commit message with a hashmark (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14931661/6309)", that will be enforce in git 2.1.
The list of default characters considered is [in this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84c9dc2c5a2d34351a06554af32501d4f99990e9#diff-8bdf812e0d5d9983d4c8fab34e829994R599):

```
# ; @ ! $ % ^ & | :
```

Comment: Is there any command that hides that logic or do I have to make that check by my own in each script?

Comment: @BertramNudelbach not that I know of. The default is '#' [per its documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/84c9dc2c5a2d34351a06554af32501d4f99990e9/Documentation/config.txt#L542-L546)

Comment: thanks for the additional information and the reference to the commits for 2.1! Maybe there is a command and somebody else knows ;-)

Comment: @BertramNudelbach I didn't see it in the source code, though.