# Github issue numbers without Hashtags

Tags: git

Is there a way in github to change the issues from using hashtags (#)? For example, issue 10 is `#10`, which causes problems when I want to squash commits using:

```
rebase -i <some branch>
```

which shows:

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# The first commit's message is:

A commit

# This is the 2nd commit message:

another commit

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Fri Mar 13 12:23:06 2015 -0500
#
# rebase in progress; onto c7e424a
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'abranch' on   'c7e424a'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   afile
```

which is fine, except it's hard to target issue 10 (`#10`), when `Lines starting with '#' will be ignored`. I've been working around this by surrounding the issue number with parens, but surely there is a better way for 'github' to work with 'git'.

Comment: Why do you want an issue number at the beginning of a line?

Comment: Because my patch targets that issue. I guess I could put it at the end. I was hoping there was a way I could specify some alpha-prefix instead of hashtags (like you can in bitbucket / jira).

Answer (score 3):

[The alternative seems to be `GH-10` or `user#10` or `user/proj#10`](https://help.github.com/articles/writing-on-github/#references).

I think parens are fine. Alternatively you could look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark) on how to circumvent the comment behavior of `git commit`.

Comment: Is there a way in github to specify `GH`? Or does it automatically understand that?

Comment: There are some especially good answers on the question you linked. Setting `core.commentchar` is a potentially really easy fix here.

Answer (score 1):

Just write `Issue: #10` or `Fix blah problem (#10)` instead of just a line starting with `#10`.

The [Git convention](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/GitCommitMessages) is to write the first line of the commit as if it is the subject of the email, then a blank line, then the body of the commit message. After that, you can put in trailing information about who contributed to a fix, what issues it affects. The convention is to write those as if they were RFC 822 (email) style headers:

```
Fixes: #10
```

or

```
Issue: #10
```

If you are going to be writing quick one-line commit messages, I recommend just putting the issue number at the end:

```
Fix blah problem (#10)
```

or:

```
Fix blah problem, issue #10
```

Comment: Thats fair. I'm too used to putting the issue number first in bitbucket. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the typical practice is to write something like:

```
fix foo bar

I added frobinator to make sure foobar keeps working in 2020.

Fixes: #10
```

as the commit message.

Since it's only lines which *start* with `#` that get ignored, and one usually wants to describe the relationship of the commit with the issue, not just mention the commit.