# Git Gui doesn't ignore lines starting with a hashmark (#) in the commit message

Tags: git, git-gui

When I use `git commit`, lines starting with a hashmark (#) are ignored, but when I commit using Git Gui, they are not.

Similar to [Start a git commit message with a hashmark (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark), only it's the opposite case.

Is there a way to tell Git Gui to ignore them?