# how not to make git's editor, for example vim, regard first line beginning with '#' as blank line

Tags: git, vim, commit

The project I work on uses `git` and demands the commit message formated as "#&#123456789 blablablabla". it's fine when I use the tool `arc diff`, but git will ignore the message because of '#' at head of line when I run `git commit --amend` to rewrite the message.

That's my situation. Thank you all.

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corecommentChar

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark