# How to let VS Code's Commit UI support a `#` in the commit message?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-commit

I need to follow a git commit message format that starts with a `#` (ex. `#1234 ...`).

This is **not** a duplicate of [Start a git commit message with a hashmark (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092) because I know about the `commentchar` and I already configured my `git` to use a different comment character:

```
gino@myrepo$ git config --global --get core.commentchar
;
gino@myrepo$ git config --get core.commentchar
;
```

I've also confirmed that it works if I commit from the command line:

```
gino@myrepo$ git log
Author: ...
Date:   Wed Nov 13 21:59:40 2019 +0900

    # Test `git commit` from terminal
    # These 2 lines should not be treated as comments
```

The problem is when I try to do my commits from [VS Code's Commit UI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_commit):

[image: vscode commit]

VS Code's Git does not seem to honor the config that `#` is not a comment, because when I check the `git log`, it only shows the 2nd line:

```
gino@myrepo$ git log
commit 1254416d309588293372b96fd1f71e30af51b1fe (HEAD -> master)
Author: ...
Date:   Wed Nov 13 22:23:17 2019 +0900

    These lines should be details.
```

It's worse when I try to use a one-line message (`#4567: blah`). The Commit UI will not allow me to commit (nothing happens when I click on the commit button) and the *Command Palette* > *Git: Commit* command will simply abort the commit (probably because it gets treated as an empty commit message).

How do I get VS Code to recognize the custom `commentchar` setting?

Notes:

- I know that VS Code uses my `git config` (global or local) because when I try changing other settings (ex. `user.name`), it applies it correctly
- It's not a duplicate of [Start a git commit message with a hashmark (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092) because I am talking about committing via VS Code's Commit UI, not via the command line
- I can't find a VS Code > Git setting related to commit messages
- I'm using VS Code 1.40.0

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with a backslash `\#` ? Not sure if that'll work.

Comment: @Bauke: Well, the line `#`-line appears but the commit message becomes `\#...` which isn't correct either.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84201#issuecomment-552840563) that seems to have what you want fixed. I don't know when that'll become available though.

Comment: @Philippe, @phd: No, it's not a duplicate, because as I've explained at the start of my post, I know about how to do it via the command line (using the `commentchar` git config) and I've confirmed that it's working. My actual problem (which I described in the rest of my post and in the title is related to doing the same via VS Code's source control UI, which doesn't seem to honor the `commentchar` config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was apparently a regression bug with the **1.40.0** version of VS Code.
(Thanks to [@Bauke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838493/how-to-let-vs-codes-commit-ui-support-a-in-the-commit-message#comment103951986_58838493) for pointing me to the relevant Github issue.)

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84201#issuecomment-552830865:

> The fix for [#6403](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/6403) made it that the input box now treats lines starting
>   with `#` as comments.

It was then "fixed" as part of the **1.40.1** version of VS Code.
(**Update 1.40.1**: The update addresses these [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22October+2019+Recovery%22+is%3Aclosed).)

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84201#issuecomment-552840563

> You should be able to commit a single line starting with `#` and
>   followed by any contents.
>
> You should be able to commit messages with lines starting with `#`
>   followed by digits. Lines starting with `#` and not followed by digits
>   will be commented out. For example, the following commit message:
>
> ```
> first line
> second line
> #third line
> # fourth line
> # 5th line
> #6th line
> #7 th line
> #8
> ```
>
> Should become:
>
> ```
> first line
> second line
> #6th line
> #7 th line
> #8
> ```
>
> Since all other lines should be commented out.

I say "fixed" because from the discussion on that Github issue, it seems that the Commit UI input box does not *exactly* follow or use git's `commentchar` config, and that it has its own parsing of which parts of the commit message are comments.

In my case, since my commit message follows the format "*single line starting with `#` and followed by any contents*", then it seems to be work. But if you are using a different format that does not fit the input box's regex rules, then it's not going to work.