# Is it possible to escape the hash(#) comment charactor in git commit messages?

Tags: git, comments

Every once in a while I want to include lines that start with `#` in git commit messages.

The question is "Is there a way to escape the `#` character so that it is not interpreted as a comment mark?"

Please answer with "Yes, it is.." or "No".

This is not a duplicate of [Start a git commit message with a hashmark (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark). I simply want a confirmation of whether it is possible to escape or not.

Comment: You can disable comment stripping as a one-off with `git commit --cleanup=whitespace`, and shut it off by default with `git config commit.cleanup whitespace`. No idea whether you'd count that as "escaping".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to escape the character.  If the comment character is `#`, and you write `\#`, then your commit message will contain the literal text `\#`.

If you need to use a different character, you can set `core.commentchar` to a different value.  This can be done on the command line with something like `git -c 'core.commentchar=;' commit`.

Run this to make it a permanent preference:

```bash
git config --global --add core.commentchar ';'
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a strong feeling it would be a no. But none of the answers on this topic spelled it out. And thanks for the `-c` tip.