# Is it possible to use a hash (#) in a .gitconfig?

Tags: git, git-config

Note to mods: This is not a duplicate of [Start a Git commit message with a hashmark (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark). That question is specifically regarding `git commit`, while this is regarding .gitconfig file syntax.

A web search will turn up many answers for how to escape a hash at the beginning of a commit message, but I'm unable to find any solution for including a hash in an alias in a .gitconfig file. This is the alias I'm trying to use:

```
[alias]
  pr-log = !git fetch && git log --reverse --pretty=format:\"### [%s](https://github.com/my-username/commit/%H)%n%n%b\" HEAD...origin/develop
```

When run in the shell this produces nicely formatted markdown, but since # is a comment  character in .gitconfig, it gets parsed as `pr-log = log --reverse --pretty=format:\"`. I tried `\#\#\#`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, as soon as I finished typing my question I found the answer in the [git aliases doc](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#What.27s_new.3F). The solution is to quote the entire alias:

```
[alias]
  pr-log = "!sh -c 'git fetch && git log --reverse --pretty=tformat:\"### [%s](https://github.com/my-username/commit/%H)%n%n%b\" HEAD...origin/develop'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your own answer, but using a shell function to get rid of a layer of quoting:

```
pr-log = "!f() { git fetch && git log --reverse --pretty=tformat:'### [%s](https://github.com/my-username/commit/%H)%n%n%b' HEAD...origin/develop; }; f"
```